# What is NGINX default cache rule

Tags: nginx, webserver, browser-cache, cache-control

I host my web application with NGINX which version is 1.19.0 on AWS EC2 which OS is CentOS 7 and I didn't set any config about cache, my config is below:

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    client_max_body_size 50000m;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;

        location / {
             proxy_pass http://;
        }
}
```

But I find my static files have cache control tag which `ETag` and `Last-Mofified` on HTTP response, like:
[image]

Not sure is cause by NGINX default cache control or not, any idea?

Now, the cache mechanism work fine event I did't set anything and I don't what to turn off the cache just want to know about more information.

Comment: Are you trying to turn these headers off? The Etag has [a directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#etag) to control it. And [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/287883/316685) has a technique for turning the other one off.

Comment: @RichardSmith I don't want to turn off those header, I just want to know where's the default setting and what's the default setting value.

My code works fine, just want to know why I didn't set anything but got those cache control

Comment: RFC7232 **requires** Nginx to send both of those headers if they can be "reasonably   and consistently determined", such as for static resources, so you don't need to set anything in the configuration file to make them appear.

Comment: @RichardSmith could I find those information on NGINX page I want to know more detail about this or just study the RFC732?